# Dupefilter in Scrapy-Redis not working as expected

Tags: python, redis, scrapy

I'm interested in using [Scrapy-Redis](https://github.com/rolando/scrapy-redis) to store scraped items in Redis. In particular, the [Redis-based request duplicates filter](https://github.com/rolando/scrapy-redis/blob/master/src/scrapy_redis/dupefilter.py) seems like a useful feature.

To start off, I adapted the spider at https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#extracting-data-in-our-spider as follows:

```
import scrapy
from tutorial.items import QuoteItem

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
    ]

    custom_settings = {'SCHEDULER': 'scrapy_redis.scheduler.Scheduler',
                       'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy_redis.dupefilter.RFPDupeFilter',
                       'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'scrapy_redis.pipelines.RedisPipeline': 300}}

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            item = QuoteItem()
            item['text'] = quote.css('span.text::text').extract_first()
            item['author'] = quote.css('small.author::text').extract_first()
            item['tags'] = quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').extract()
            yield item
```

where I generated the project using `scrapy startproject tutorial` at the command line and defined `QuoteItem` in `items.py` as

```
import scrapy

class QuoteItem(scrapy.Item):
    text = scrapy.Field()
    author = scrapy.Field()
    tags = scrapy.Field()
```

Basically, I've implemented the settings in the "Usage" section of the README in the [settings per-spider](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#settings-per-spider) and made the spider `yield` an `Item` object instead of a regular Python dictionary. (I figured this would be necessary to trigger the [Item Pipeline](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html)).

Now, if I crawl the spider using `scrapy crawl quotes` from the command line and then do `redis-cli`, I see a `quotes:items` key:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "quotes:items"
```

which is a list of length 20:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> llen quotes:items
(integer) 20
```

If I run `scrapy crawl quotes` again, the length of the list doubles to 40:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> llen quotes:items
(integer) 40
```

However, I would expect the length of `quotes:items` to still be 20, since I have simply re-scraped the same pages. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scrapy-redis doesn't filter duplicate items automatically.

The (requests) dupefilter is about the requests in a crawl. What you want seems to be something similar to the deltafetch middleware: https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-deltafetch

You would need to adapt deltafetch to work with a distributed storage, perhaps redis' bitmap feature will fit this case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Rolando. A follow-up question: I see that deltafetch is implemented as [spider middleware](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html) and implements a `process_spider_output` method which operates (among other things) on a `Response` object. In my case, however, if the URL has already been visited I don't even need to get the `Response` again. I'm guessing it would make the scraping faster to modify the dupefilter such that it keeps the (fingerprints of) visited URLs in a database?

Comment: deltafetch filters out the new requests generated from a response, customized by `deltafetch_key`. The key can be the URL itself, or an ID extracted from the URL, etc. It works great as long you don't need to download the URL to tell whether the item is already scraped (most of the cases).

Comment: Did that solution, (deltafetch) work? Looks like I have a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I fixed the problem in the end. First of all, as pointed out to me in a separate question, [How to implement a custom dupefilter in Scrapy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43803605/how-to-implement-a-custom-dupefilter-in-scrapy), using the `start_urls` class variable results in an implementation of `start_requests` in which the yielded `Request` objects have `dont_filter=True`. To disable this and use the default `dont_filter=False` instead, I implemented `start_requests` directly:

```
import scrapy
from tutorial.items import QuoteItem

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    custom_settings = {
                       'SCHEDULER': 'scrapy_redis.scheduler.Scheduler',
                       'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'tutorial.dupefilter.RedisDupeFilter',
                       'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'scrapy_redis.pipelines.RedisPipeline': 300}
                       }

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            item = QuoteItem()
            item['text'] = quote.css('span.text::text').extract_first()
            item['author'] = quote.css('small.author::text').extract_first()
            item['tags'] = quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').extract()
            yield item
```

Secondly, as pointed out by Rolando, the fingerprints aren't by default persisted across different crawls. To implement this, I subclassed Scrapy-Redis' `RFPDupeFilter` class:

```
import scrapy_redis.dupefilter
from scrapy_redis.connection import get_redis_from_settings


class RedisDupeFilter(scrapy_redis.dupefilter.RFPDupeFilter):
    @classmethod
    def from_settings(cls, settings):
        server = get_redis_from_settings(settings)
        key = "URLs_seen"                               # Use a fixed key instead of one containing a timestamp
        debug = settings.getbool('DUPEFILTER_DEBUG')
        return cls(server=server, key=key, debug=debug)

    def request_seen(self, request):
        added = self.server.sadd(self.key, request.url)
        return added == 0

    def clear(self):
        pass                                            # Don't delete the key from Redis
```

The main differences are (1) the `key` is set to a fixed value (not one containing a time stamp) and (2) the `clear` method, which in Scrapy-Redis' implementation deletes the `key` from Redis, is effectively disabled.

Now, when I run `scrapy crawl quotes` the second time, I see the expected log output

```
2017-05-05 15:13:46 [scrapy_redis.dupefilter] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
```

and no items are scraped.

Comment: The difference is that `deltafetch` persist the information across different crawl sessions, using a custom key. While the dupefilter is meant only for a single crawl and entirely based on the request fingerprint (canonical URL hash). In this case, as we persist the dupefilter in redis, and if the canonical URL is good enough to filter already seen items, then your solution is equivalent to what `deltafetch` does.