# How to implement a custom dupefilter in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to create a custom [DUPEFILTER_CLASS](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#dupefilter-class) in Scrapy, but it seems to not be working. Here is my example Spider:

```
import scrapy
from tutorial.items import QuoteItem

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
    ]

    custom_settings = {
                       'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'tutorial.dupefilter.RedisDupeFilter',
                       }

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            item = QuoteItem()
            item['text'] = quote.css('span.text::text').extract_first()
            item['author'] = quote.css('small.author::text').extract_first()
            item['tags'] = quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').extract()
            yield item
```

where `items.py` is

```
import scrapy

class QuoteItem(scrapy.Item):
    text = scrapy.Field()
    author = scrapy.Field()
    tags = scrapy.Field()
```

and `dupefilter.py`, which is next to `items.py` in the directory tree, is

```
import logging
import redis
import scrapy.dupefilters

class RedisDupeFilter(scrapy.dupefilters.BaseDupeFilter):
    def __init__(self, server, key):
        self.server = server
        self.key = key
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    @classmethod
    def from_settings(cls, settings):
        server = redis.Redis()
        key = "URLs_seen"
        return cls(server=server, key=key)

    def request_seen(self, request):
        self.logger.debug("Checking whether request {request} has been seen yet...".format(request=request))
        added = self.server.sadd(self.key, request.url)
        return added == 0
```

Prior to running the spider, I started Redis using `redis-server` at the command line. Then in the project directory, I started the crawl using

```
scrapy crawl quotes
```

and observe the following log output:

```
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.3 started (bot: tutorial)
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tutorial.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tutorial.spiders'], 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'BOT_NAME': 'tutorial'}
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/> (referer: None)
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/> (referer: None)
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/>
{'author': u'Albert Einstein',
 'tags': [u'change', u'deep-thoughts', u'thinking', u'world'],
 'text': u'\u201cThe world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.\u201d'}
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/>
{'author': u'J.K. Rowling',
 'tags': [u'abilities', u'choices'],
 'text': u'\u201cIt is our choices, Harry, that show what we truly are, far more than our abilities.\u201d'}
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/>
{'author': u'Albert Einstein',
 'tags': [u'inspirational', u'life', u'live', u'miracle', u'miracles'],
 'text': u'\u201cThere are only two ways to live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as though everything is a miracle.\u201d'}
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/>
{'author': u'Jane Austen',
 'tags': [u'aliteracy', u'books', u'classic', u'humor'],
 'text': u'\u201cThe person, be it gentleman or lady, who has not pleasure in a good novel, must be intolerably stupid.\u201d'}
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/>
{'author': u'Marilyn Monroe',
 'tags': [u'be-yourself', u'inspirational'],
 'text': u"\u201cImperfection is beauty, madness is genius and it's better to be absolutely ridiculous than absolutely boring.\u201d"}
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/>
{'author': u'Albert Einstein',
 'tags': [u'adulthood', u'success', u'value'],
 'text': u'\u201cTry not to become a man of success. Rather become a man of value.\u201d'}
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/>
{'author': u'Andr\xe9 Gide',
 'tags': [u'life', u'love'],
 'text': u'\u201cIt is better to be hated for what you are than to be loved for what you are not.\u201d'}
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/>
{'author': u'Thomas A. Edison',
 'tags': [u'edison', u'failure', u'inspirational', u'paraphrased'],
 'text': u"\u201cI have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.\u201d"}
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/>
{'author': u'Eleanor Roosevelt',
 'tags': [u'misattributed-eleanor-roosevelt'],
 'text': u"\u201cA woman is like a tea bag; you never know how strong it is until it's in hot water.\u201d"}
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/>
{'author': u'Steve Martin',
 'tags': [u'humor', u'obvious', u'simile'],
 'text': u'\u201cA day without sunshine is like, you know, night.\u201d'}
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/>
{'author': u'Marilyn Monroe',
 'tags': [u'friends',
          u'heartbreak',
          u'inspirational',
          u'life',
          u'love',
          u'sisters'],
 'text': u"\u201cThis life is what you make it. No matter what, you're going to mess up sometimes, it's a universal truth. But the good part is you get to decide how you're going to mess it up. Girls will be your friends - they'll act like it anyway. But just remember, some come, some go. The ones that stay with you through everything - they're your true best friends. Don't let go of them. Also remember, sisters make the best friends in the world. As for lovers, well, they'll come and go too. And baby, I hate to say it, most of them - actually pretty much all of them are going to break your heart, but you can't give up because if you give up, you'll never find your soulmate. You'll never find that half who makes you whole and that goes for everything. Just because you fail once, doesn't mean you're gonna fail at everything. Keep trying, hold on, and always, always, always believe in yourself, because if you don't, then who will, sweetie? So keep your head high, keep your chin up, and most importantly, keep smiling, because life's a beautiful thing and there's so much to smile about.\u201d"}
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/>
{'author': u'J.K. Rowling',
 'tags': [u'courage', u'friends'],
 'text': u'\u201cIt takes a great deal of bravery to stand up to our enemies, but just as much to stand up to our friends.\u201d'}
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/>
{'author': u'Albert Einstein',
 'tags': [u'simplicity', u'understand'],
 'text': u"\u201cIf you can't explain it to a six year old, you don't understand it yourself.\u201d"}
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/>
{'author': u'Bob Marley',
 'tags': [u'love'],
 'text': u"\u201cYou may not be her first, her last, or her only. She loved before she may love again. But if she loves you now, what else matters? She's not perfect\u2014you aren't either, and the two of you may never be perfect together but if she can make you laugh, cause you to think twice, and admit to being human and making mistakes, hold onto her and give her the most you can. She may not be thinking about you every second of the day, but she will give you a part of her that she knows you can break\u2014her heart. So don't hurt her, don't change her, don't analyze and don't expect more than she can give. Smile when she makes you happy, let her know when she makes you mad, and miss her when she's not there.\u201d"}
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/>
{'author': u'Dr. Seuss',
 'tags': [u'fantasy'],
 'text': u'\u201cI like nonsense, it wakes up the brain cells. Fantasy is a necessary ingredient in living.\u201d'}
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/>
{'author': u'Douglas Adams',
 'tags': [u'life', u'navigation'],
 'text': u'\u201cI may not have gone where I intended to go, but I think I have ended up where I needed to be.\u201d'}
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/>
{'author': u'Elie Wiesel',
 'tags': [u'activism',
          u'apathy',
          u'hate',
          u'indifference',
          u'inspirational',
          u'love',
          u'opposite',
          u'philosophy'],
 'text': u"\u201cThe opposite of love is not hate, it's indifference. The opposite of art is not ugliness, it's indifference. The opposite of faith is not heresy, it's indifference. And the opposite of life is not death, it's indifference.\u201d"}
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/>
{'author': u'Friedrich Nietzsche',
 'tags': [u'friendship',
          u'lack-of-friendship',
          u'lack-of-love',
          u'love',
          u'marriage',
          u'unhappy-marriage'],
 'text': u'\u201cIt is not a lack of love, but a lack of friendship that makes unhappy marriages.\u201d'}
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/>
{'author': u'Mark Twain',
 'tags': [u'books', u'contentment', u'friends', u'friendship', u'life'],
 'text': u'\u201cGood friends, good books, and a sleepy conscience: this is the ideal life.\u201d'}
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/>
{'author': u'Allen Saunders',
 'tags': [u'fate',
          u'life',
          u'misattributed-john-lennon',
          u'planning',
          u'plans'],
 'text': u'\u201cLife is what happens to us while we are making other plans.\u201d'}
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 675,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 5976,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 5, 10, 45, 15, 881028),
 'item_scraped_count': 20,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 24,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 5, 10, 45, 15, 553906)}
2017-05-05 12:45:15 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

What puzzles me is that I don't see anywhere in the logs `"Checking whether request ... has been seen yet..."` as I put in the `self.logger.debug` call in the `request_seen` method of the `RedisDupeFilter`. In short, I see no confirmation whether the dupefilter is actually working. (It's probably not, because if I run the `crawl` again I see the same output).

How can I get my custom `DUPEFILTER_CLASS` to work?

Comment: By default, what's in `start_urls` gets converted to `scrapy.Request` objects with `dont_filter=True` (see [how the default `start_requests` method is implemented](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/b0388e49b41c4c2e96503605a0955f1c54fe02b5/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py#L69)), so they don't go through the dupefilter. And you are not generating requests in your `parse` callback, so no other Request goes through dupefilter either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [paul trmbrth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2572383/paul-trmbrth)'s comment, instead of using the `start_urls` class variable I overrode the `start_requests` method as in the [Scrapy Tutorial](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#our-first-spider):

```
import scrapy
from tutorial.items import QuoteItem

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    custom_settings = {'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'tutorial.dupefilter.RedisDupeFilter'}

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            item = QuoteItem()
            item['text'] = quote.css('span.text::text').extract_first()
            item['author'] = quote.css('small.author::text').extract_first()
            item['tags'] = quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').extract()
            yield item
```

This uses the fact that the default value for `dont_filter` in the constructor of a `Request` object is `False` (cf. https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects).

The dupefilter now works (given that a `redis` server is running in the background): the second time I `scrapy crawl quotes` nothing gets scraped.